# Finding the derivative of $(\frac{a+x}{a-x})^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

This is a very simple problem, but I am stuck on one step:

Differentiate $(\frac{a+x}{a-x})^{\frac{3}{2}}$

Now, this is what I have done:

$$
(\frac{a+x}{a-x})^{\frac{3}{2}} \\
\implies \frac{\delta}{\delta y}\frac{f}{g} \\
\implies gf' = (a-x)^{\frac{3}{2}} \times \frac{3}{2} (a+x)^{\frac{1}{2}} \times 2 \\
\implies fg' \implies (a+x)^{\frac{3}{2}} \times \frac{3}{2} (a-x)^{\frac{1}{2}} \times 0 = 0 \\
\implies \frac{(a-x)^{\frac{3}{2}} \times 3 (a+x)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{(a-x)^3}\\
\implies \frac{(a-x)^{\frac{3}{2}} - 3\sqrt{a+x}}{(a-x)^3}
$$

But the answer is:
$$
\frac{3\times a (a+x)^{\frac{1}{3}}}{(a-x)^{\frac{5}{2}}}
$$

WolframAlpha shows:

$$
\frac{3a \sqrt{\frac{a+x}{a-x}}}{(a-x)^2}
$$

Another Answer (Somehow I got this):

$$
\frac{3 \sqrt{\frac{a+x}{a-x}}}{2(a-x)}
$$

==================

EDIT 1:
What about:

$$
y = (\frac{a+x}{a-x})^{\frac{3}{2}} \\
y = u^{\frac{3}{2}} \hspace{0.5cm} ; \hspace{0.5cm} u = \frac{a+x}{a-x}\\
\implies \frac{3}{2}u^{\frac{1}{2}} \hspace{0.5cm} ; \hspace{0.5cm} \frac{(0+1)\times (a-x) - [ -1 (a+x) ]}{(a-x)^2} \\
\implies \frac{2a}{(a-x)^2} \\
\implies \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2a}{(a-x)^2}} = \frac{3}{2} \times \frac{\sqrt{2a}}{a-x} 
$$

Comment: Where did the $0$ come from? Derivatives of this form just require careful bookkeeping

Comment: You seem to have errors in your computations. The "$\times 2$" and "$\times 0$" are wrong, and the second one is missing a "$\times(-1)$".

Comment: Differentiating $(a-x) = 1\times a^{1-1} - 1\times x^{1-1} = 0$ that's how. And, similarly: $ (a+x) = 1.(a^{1-1}) + 1.(x^{1-1}) $

Comment: @Chinny84 Now I got it. We're treating $a$ as a constant, and since constants differentiate to 0...

Comment: I understand that concept but you should have two terms for $fg'$ one for the derivative of $a$ and one for the non-constant $x$. Maybe I just misread what you did.

Comment: Have you considered logarithmic differentiation?  It will simplify the analysis here.

Comment: Can you expound a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there was something flawed in my calculation:

$$
y = f(g(x)) \\ 
y' = \frac{dy}{du} \times \frac{du}{dx} \\
$$

Let's see it again:
$$
y = (\frac{a+x}{a-x})^{\frac{3}{2}} \\ 
y = u^{\frac{3}{2}} \hspace{0.5cm} ; \hspace{0.5cm} u = \frac{a+x}{a-x} \\
\frac{dy}{du} = \frac{3}{2} \times u^{\frac{1}{2}} \implies  \frac{3}{2} \times (\frac{a+x}{a-x})^{\frac{1}{2}}  \\
\frac{du}{dx} = \frac{2a}{(a-x)^2} \\
y' = \frac{dy}{du} \times \frac{du}{dx} \\
...\\
\frac{3a(a+x)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{(a-x)^{\frac{5}{2}}}
$$

Answer (score 1):

i think the right answer is this here
$$\frac{3}{2} \sqrt{\frac{a+x}{a-x}}
   \left(\frac{a+x}{(a-x)^2}+\frac{1}{a-x}\right)$$

Comment: I have the first part of the answer; chain rule, then quotient rule, but the second part...?

Comment: bring the second part together and you will see it